# Heroku Application Error after deplyoing code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, heroku

I developed a simple chat application using node js when I run the code using localhost the entire application works smoothly but every time I deploy the code to Heroku it fails

these are the logs I am getting ...
can someone explain what should be done

```
020-07-07T09:41:22.714227+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=aathma-nirbhar-bharat.herokuapp.com request_id=3649cd8a-ce4f-481f-9317-a462497c433b fwd="27.5.227.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-07T09:41:55.531781+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-07-07T09:41:55.550121+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-07-07T09:41:55.624470+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-07-07T09:41:55.663460+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-07-07T09:41:56.628289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aathma-nirbhar-bharat.herokuapp.com request_id=7ca88f42-b5a1-49da-8449-5697f6584fd0 fwd="27.5.227.1" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-07T09:42:28.778832+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aathma-nirbhar-bharat.herokuapp.com request_id=78879817-9f44-46cd-8982-2a2560b445f3 fwd="27.5.227.1" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-07T09:42:29.729147+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aathma-nirbhar-bharat.herokuapp.com request_id=911afd24-e560-4a53-9883-190169922bab fwd="27.5.227.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: What port you used ?

Comment: You are not binding to the `PORT` https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

Comment: i did use  const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT

Comment: server.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`the app is live and running on stark ${port} mr.jarvis `)
})